# Python for ArcGIS - Spatial query using field values as buffer

Tags: python, spatial, arcgis

I am writing a python code that will do a spatial query to select point features within a distance of all line features in a feature class.

However, my issue is that the search distance should be different for each line feature. These values are contained in a Field in the attribute table called 'S_DIST'.

Based on my research, it seems that a search cursor would be the most suitable option to loop through rows of the attribute table. I have found some information on using spatial queries with buffers, in the link below. However, I have not been able to find an example that used a field value as a parameter in a tool and am wondering if this is even possible.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/does-arcpy-have-a-spatial-search-function-for-geometry

Any suggestions or recommended sources would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a field from your input's attribute table as distance for Buffer. If you want then to select all points in all the buffer zones at once, this is enough. Is this what you want to achieve?

[image]